# Bigquery time range

Tags: sql, date, time, google-bigquery

I want to get a list of orders that are placed in a given date range, but exclude the orders placed between 2pm-10pm.
Can anyone help me to complete the below query

```
select * 
from abc 
where 
    date(order_created) between '2021-05-22' and '2021-05-24' 
    and not between <order placed between 2pm-10pm>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `time()` to get the time part.  That allows:

```
date(order_created) between '2021-05-22' and '2021-05-24' and
time(order_created) not between '14:00:00' and '20:00:00'
```

Note that this excludes both the end points.  More commonly, you would want to exclude the first but keep the second:

```
date(order_created) between '2021-05-22' and '2021-05-24' and
(time(order_created) < '14:00:00' or
 time(order_created) >= '20:00:00'
)
```

Comment: or `time(order_created) not between '14:00:00' and '19:59:59'` :o)

Answer (score 0):

Try:
`and EXTRACT(TIME FROM order_created) not between '14:00:00' and '22:00:00'`

Note: I'm assuming your `order_created` column contains the time as well. FYI: in BigQuery there are two types of fields that contain date and time: *Timestamp*, and *Datetime*, so your `order_created` field is likely one of those two types. The SQL differs slightly between manipulating one type or the other, but the `EXTRACT` function works on both.